# Using Regex to replace a value in a string from a list of items in array

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm not sure I'm asking what is possible.  I have a situation

```
Dim animalList as string = "Dog|Cat|Bird|Mouse"
Dim animal_story_string as string = "One day I was walking down the street and I saw a dog"
Dim hasAnAnimalonList as Boolean 
Dim animals() as String =   animalList.Split("|")
Dim regex As New Regex("\b" & String.Join("\b|\b", animals) & "\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
If regex.IsMatch(animal_story_string) Then
   hasAnAnimalonList = True
  'Here I would like to replace/format the animal found with HTML bold tags so it would look 
   like  "One day I was walking down the street and I saw a <b>dog</>"
End If
```

In the past I would loop each value in the animalList and if a match is found replace it at that time.  Like

```
     For Each animal As string in animals
      ' I would replace every animal in the list
      ' If Cat and Birds and Mouse were not in the string it did not matter 
        animal_story_string = animal_story_string.Replace(animal,"<b>" + animal + "</b>" 
     Next
```

Is there a way to do it using a Regex function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there a way to do it using a Regex function?*

Yes, call [`Regex.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) method and split the `Dog|Cat|Bird|Mouse` string to join the result and create the regex pattern as shown below, you can replace the matches in one line using a `MatchEvaluator` function.

```vb
Dim animalList = "Dog|Cat|Bird|Mouse"
Dim regexPattern = String.Join("|", animalList.Split("|"c).Select(Function(x) $"\b{x}\b"))
Dim animal_story_string = "One day I was walking down the street and I saw a dog or maybe a fat cat! I didn't see a bird though."
Dim hasAnAnimalonList = Regex.IsMatch(animal_story_string, regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

If hasAnAnimalonList Then
    Dim replace = Regex.Replace(
        animal_story_string,
        regexPattern,
        Function(m) $"<b>{m.Value}</b>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    Console.WriteLine(replace)
End If
```

Writes in the console:

```
One day I was walking down the street and I saw a <b>dog</b> or maybe a fat <b>cat</b>! I didn't see a <b>bird</b> though.
```

... and in HTML renderer...

One day I was walking down the street and I saw a **dog** or maybe a fat **cat**! I didn't see a **bird** though.

Comment: This looks great-- I'll give it a try   Thanks  Regex is extremely powerful

Comment: @Bill I've fixed the regex pattern to not match for example `dog` in hotdog...etc

Comment: Thank you. I actually have a use for both situations.  As you can imagine, the Cat's and Dog's are just a simplified example.  I'll push my luck and ask do you have a simple way for Regex to handle and &?  So if I wanted to format in a sentence "Bob & Mary" but the list has "Bob and Mary" .  Currently in the sentence I test if & exists and if it does I add to the list an additional item with replacing "and" with "&".  I highlight format if a researcher publishes using their department of  "Cell and Molecular Pharmacology" or "Cell & Molecular Pharmacology".  Have no control over entry

Comment: @Bill You are welcome. I'm not sure if you mean something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/INzlQi/1) or an explicit one like [this](https://regex101.com/r/OQZQxl/1).  It Depends, maybe a string method call like: `Dim s = "Cell and Molecular Pharmacology".Replace("and", "&")` could be more efficient in some cases. Keep it simple.

Comment: Yup-- I'm doing the replace and that's working fine.  Very similar to matching joined combined names with or without hyphens like: Smith Jones and Smith-Jones  same person just a different input.   Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
/(?:^|(?<= ))(Dog|Cat|Bird|Mouse)(?:(?= )|$)/i
```

or even

```
/\b(Dog|Cat|Bird|Mouse)\b/i
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/V4Uhg7/1

will do what you want?